# Laravel | LinkedIn and Socialite - Not passing parameters

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, linkedin-api

I'm having an issue with socialite on Laravel, I want to add a LinkedIn login on my website, I already added a Twitter login which is 100% working. My issue is that when I do `return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();` , it redirect me to a link like this:

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?**client_id=**&**redirect_uri=**&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress&response_type=code&state=XXX

And I get an error because as you can see, the URL doesn't have the **client_id** and **redirect_uri** parameters..
If I had them manually, everything work. I checked my .env file, my services.php and my SocialAuthController too.. I can't figure out.. Here is my .env file:

```
LINKEDIN_ID=XXX123XXX123XXX
LINKEDIN_SECRET=XXX456XXX456XXX
```

My services file:

```
    'linkedin' => [
    'client_id' => env('LINKEDIN_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('LINKEDIN_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/linkedin/callback',
],
```

My SocialAuthController:

```
public function redirectToProvider($driver)
{
    if ($driver === 'linkedin')
    {
        return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();
    }
}
```

And finally my routes:

```
Route::get('auth/social', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@show')->name('social.login');
Route::get('login/{driver}', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider')->name('social.oauth');
Route::get('login/{driver}/callback', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback')->name('social.callback');
```

I did everything like this for the Twitter login and it's working perfectly..

Comment: Do you run `php artisan config:cache` before adding `LINKEDIN_ID` and `LINKEDIN_SECRET`? Try `cache:clear`. Is it works?

Comment: Also always rerun php artisan serve after editing .env file

Comment: @DharmaSaputra Thank you so much! I was going on this, php artisan config:cache reloaded all my config, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('/shopping', 'GoogleShopping\GShoppingController@index');//redirect to home
```

**config/services.php**

```
 'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_APP_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL'),//it must be same the home url
    ]
```

**Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

```
try {
   $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
   return view('/');
 }

 return redirect()->to('/shopping');
```

Is very important clean the cache `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear`